# Cloudcontrol first push error

Tags: git, cloudcontrol

I've created account on cloudControl and I'm trying to do my first push. So I start with:

```
cctrluser key.add
cctrlapp koptusapp/default push
```

but I get error:

```
    Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Command '['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\git.exe', 'push', u'ssh://koptusapp
@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git', 'master']' returned non-zero exit status
128
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cctrlapp", line 481, in <module>
  File "cctrlapp", line 93, in main
  File "cctrlapp", line 475, in parse_cmdline
  File "cctrl\common.pyo", line 99, in run
  File "cctrl\app.pyo", line 1080, in push
NameError: global name 'exit' is not defined
```

Could someone help me with that?

EDIT: I don't know if it changes anything, but to store that project I use bitbucket (git) so git is already here

Answer (score 0):

did you created the application before? This can be done via:

```
cctrlapp APP_NAME create [java, php, python, ruby, nodejs]
```